# The mystery of the Samurai

Tags: visual, cipher, geocaching

In the year 1612, the famous samurai Miyamoto Musashi fought against Sasaki Kojirō, in the famous duel of Funa-jima.

Miyamoto killed his opponent who, shortly before his death, gave Miyamoto a strange piece of paper.

Sasaki said to Miyamoto that he had received it years earlier from a strange old treasure hunter; the hunter confessed that he had buried all the treasures he'd found in his long life, but it would not be easy to find them.  Sasaki also said that he'd never understood the meaning of the paper.

Miyamoto died many years later, but the message still remains a secret to this day.

**Where the treasures are buried?**

Hint 1 :

> Try to resolve before the first two horizontal rows; after 'rotate' the grid of 90° and try to solve the other seven 'vertical rows'...

Hint 2 :

> The colors aren't relevant for the solution, image the cells with binary code...

Hint 3 :

> Miyamoto did not have the technological know-how to solve the puzzle

Hint 4 :

> The first row is a word. The second row is a word.

[image]

Comment: Geocaching tag?

Comment: @Micha Sprengers yes!

Comment: Is this fiction or real?

Comment: Small contribution, the 4 blocks on the left, if not difformed, could form a captcha once combined. can't verify it now :)

Comment: @Question Asker Fiction mixed story

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer No, the 4 block on the left aren't part of a captcha

Comment: For people wondering about the story, I have found an online link to it's pdf [here](https://teachthesky.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/panel-excerpt-duel-at-funa-jima.pdf).

Comment: It appears to be laid over a slightly different image. The blue and black squares don't match the image behind it. Look at the left edge for ease of seeing the different image.  The top row of pixels also looks funny. May contain a message.

Comment: @Z.Dailey no, it's only a special effect, the different image on the left is no important. You can watch only the "upper" image

Comment: @StefanoLonati all I know is that after staring at this for a min my eyes get all wonky. Haha.

Comment: @Z.Dailey ahah..however it is not very difficult to solve , just look it in the right perspective ; )

Comment: Why do I have the impression I can *nearly* read it, when I glance at it from a flat angle.... Maybe, because I've been sitting too long in front of a screen today :c)

Comment: Possibly by combining the top blocks with the blocks running down the side you could form Japanese characters.

Comment: Looks like the last column of "black" boxes (the 7th column overall) are not really black, rather dark blue. You can see more easily looking at an angle (depending on screen).

Comment: @George Reith no Japanese characters :)

Comment: @Dan Russell no, the colors of the cells are only five: white, blue, green, black and azure. The colors are not important to solve the puzzle

Comment: Did Miyamoto Musashi and Sasaki Kojirō have sufficient knowledge to solve this puzzle? If binary calculus and/or geographic coordinates are necessary to solve this puzzle, it would be nice to mention that it requires newer technology than that of the story.

Comment: @fffred You're right , I have included this note in a new Hint, thank you!

Comment: 7x7 squares ... Looks like it could be some 7-bit ASCII, but in any orientation, it does not make sense.

Comment: I'm curious why you chose that for the second line?

Comment: @paste because I love "Paperino" (Donald Duck in italian) ;)

Comment: @StefanoLonati Ah cool. I remember my Italian friends talking about Topolino

Comment: @paste I see that you have solved two of my puzzle, have you try with "Where is my technological guinea pig?"  ?  It's unanswered! ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The top two lines:

> Morse code (blue is dot, beige is dash):
>  The top line is Vigenere
>  The bottom line is Donald, which I'm guessing is the key for the Vigenere cipher

The four squares below:

> They are ASCII codes, laid out vertically. Starting with the top 7x7 square and reading across we get:
>  `T R R D S U R`
>  `0 0 E Q k E 1`
>  `R R 4 p V h M`
>  `V X u P T T u`

From there:

> Rotate 90 degrees, so that the binary representations read left to right, which gives:
>  `R1MuUEhTSkVTDQpPRE4uR0RXT0RV` 
>  Decode using Base64 to get:
>  `GS.PHSJES`
>  `ODN.GDWODU`
>  Then apply our Vigenere decipher with DONALD as the key to get:
>  DE.CHHGBE
>  BDC.DAIBDJ
>  Taking A=0, B=1, etc., we get coordinates: 34.277614, 132.308139

The treasure is buried by

> Mt. Misen, on the island of Itsukushima in Hatsukaichi, Hiroshima, Japan

Comment: vero good job!!

Comment: @StefanoLonati man, what a workout!

Comment: How do you know base64 needs to be used?

Answer (score 4):

The first two lines are

> Morse code: `..._ .. __. . _. . ._. . _.. ___ _. ._ ._.. _..`
>  which translate to : VIGENERE DONALD.
>  I imagine that the vigenere decryption must apply to the rest of the puzzle yet to be solved.

I tried to manipulate the four 7x7 squares by

> rotating them 90° and converting each 7bit segment into ASCII, which does not provide much:
>  T ? R V
>  R ? R X
>  R # 4 u
>  D ) p P
>  S 5 V T
>  U # h T
>  R ? M u
>  Question marks are non-printing characters. And all non-alphabetical characters cannot be vigenered ...

thus without success ...